# Are pictures lost forever if using TWRP to wipe data?

Tags: data-recovery, twrp

I have the following problem: I accidentally deleted an important picture and tried to recover it;
Using DiskDigger (without root) I only find the low quality version of the picture - I read that I need to have root access to search for all pictures which I did not have - hence since I am using Android Oreo on my S8+ the only possibility I saw to root it was with TWRP and SuperSu using the way which is described here:

https://www.androidexplained.com/galaxy-s8-root-supersu/

Basically I did the following: OEM Unlock, then using the Downloadmode and Odin to put the TWRP tar file on it, then in TWRP I wiped out data, installed the no-verity.zip file and then installed the supersu.zip file and my root was successful;

Now I actually thought that when I use disk digger again, that all my pictures now can be restored (since the 'wiping' took like 10s it is impossible that all the storage got really overwritten)

Unfortunately, when running now the programme with root access I can't find any pictures I had before the 'wiping' - is that normal? Is there any way to recover it? Or did I screw it up?

One thing maybe worth mentioning is that the supersu failed to install in the first place and I played with the data format - precisely I changed the /data directory from EXT4 to exFAT and back because I thought maybe this would solve the issue;

I would be extemely thankful about any kind of comment about it - thank you so much

Comment: Normally the pictures are saved on the internal storage e.g. /sdcard0/DCIM/Camera and this partition is normally not deleted when you flash TWRP. If you changed the file system for /data all data are lost on this partition (/data)  what means that all your user apps should have gone! If your picture was indeed on the internal storage and you didnt format that, the chances are given that you can recover it by using adb and some data recovery tool (undelete program).

Comment: Well I changed the format for /data where the picture were saved.... So they are gone? I mean changing the format took 3s - is it really possible that within those 3s everything got destroyed?

Comment: Yes, maybe with a tool like TestDisk you could restore such things, but not sure how to use that tool on internal storage of Android

Comment: To change the format, you have to format the partition, that deletes all content. Normally you get a warning before doing so.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to recover files from factory reset. The userdata partition is encrypted and the encryption key is wiped. also new key is generated, makes it nearly impossible to recover the old key

Do not unlock bootloader it will perform factory reset. look for exploit root method on locked bootloader (android < 6.0 only)